# Flutter app error message: No Firebase App

Tags: firebase, flutter

I recently went back to a Flutter project I've not touched for a couple of months and updated a few bits and pieces. Now, when I run the app in my emulator, I get the message:

[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created

I added this line of code to initialize it in the app: await Firebase.initializeApp();... but it now doesn't appear to connect to my Firebase, just an empty one that I presume it has created on the fly.

This was my original code, which according to this site is the correct way to initialize the app: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initialization,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {...
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? The original app on my phone works fine with Firebase, so I presume it's something to do with updating Flutter, Firebase to the latest versions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should initalize your app in the `main` function before you run your app, not in the `MyApp` widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(); // add this line
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it wasn't anything to do with the incorrect Firebase app. I did initialize it in the main function, but in debugging I found that it was hitting an error in reading an object from the database. It was just incorrectly defined. I fixed that and it works now.

Thanks